# Joining MANY to MANY with Junction Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

Okay, at this point I just don't know what to do next. I just started learning joins in mySQL and what I'm trying to do is to join 2 tables through it's junction table `(Many-to-Many)` relationship. But the examples in http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp which I'm following didn't say anything about `MANY-TO-MANY` tables.

I have 3 tables.

1.) curriculum

2.) curriculumsubjects `--the junction table`

3.) subject

**curriculum**

```
id PK
name
description
yearLevel
syStart
syEnd
```

**curriculumsubjects** `--junction table`

```
id PK
curriculumId FK
subjectCode FK
```

**subject**

```
code PK
name
yrLevel
description
```

Desired result is to show the **subject code**, **subject name**, **subject description**, **subject yearlevel** if supplied or if given the `curriculum name` and `curriculum year level` on procedure call.

So here's what I did.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getCurriculumSubjects` (IN p_CurcName varchar(50),IN p_yrLevel varchar(50))
BEGIN
    SELECT `subject`.`code`,`subject`.`name`,`subject`.yrLevel, `subject`.description
    FROM `subject`

    LEFT OUTER JOIN curriculumsubjects
    ON `subject`.`code` = curriculumsubjects.subjectCode

    LEFT OUTER JOIN curriculum
    ON curriculum.id = curriculumsubjects.curriculumId
    WHERE curriculumsubjects.id = (SELECT id FROM curriculum WHERE `name` = p_CurcName AND yearLevel = p_yrLevel);

END
```

Currently there's one record on the `curriculum` table and 2 subjects record on `subject` table.

**CURRICULUM Table Screenshot**

[image]

**SUBJECT Table Screenshot**

[image]

**CURRICULUMSUBJECT Table Screenshot**

[image]

But when I ran the script, I get nothing.

[image]

I mean, how do I properly use left join to fix this problem?
Can I join more tables instead of just 2?

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can join any number of tables

Comment: Change `WHERE` to `AND`

Comment: @Strawberry ???? Sorry where/What

Comment: What are the arguments you use in the call to the stored procedure?

Comment: What **exactly** is the problem you are having

Comment: @RiggsFolly first, thanks for asking. I get no results when I ran the procedure even if there are record and even if I supply the matching record. So I think I'm not doing the left join correctly.

Comment: @RiggsFolly To paraphrase the OP's query: `LEFT JOIN x ON ... WHERE x.id = [ANYTHING OTHER THAN NULL]` is the same as an INNER JOIN. If the OP really wants an OUTER JOIN, then they should replace the `WHERE` with `AND`.

Comment: @Adder thanks too for asking. I did CALL getCurriculumSubjects('Test Curriculum','Grade 1'); These two values passed to stored procedures' parameter: p_CurcName and p_yrLevel

Comment: The problem is that luckily `curriculumsubjects.id`  will never match `curriculum.id` and result will be empty. One some unlucky occasion they will match and we'll get total nonsence. :) Need `curriculumsubjects.curriculumId` really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this achieves what you are asking:

```
select s.code, s.name, s.description, s.yrLevel
from subject s
inner join curriculumsubject cs on s.code = cs.subjectCode
inner join curriculum c on cs.curriculumId = c.ID
where c.name = p_CurcName and c.yearLevel = p_yrLevel
```

I don't think left join is appropriate, unless you want to return empty values for the subject, when the parameter values exist in curriculum, but there's no link to subject. If you want to return rows only where there's a matching subject, then inner join is the correct solution.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. Like I mentioned I just started learning joins and your solution helped me to fully understand the simple or Inner Join. So what I did first is analyzed the effect of join on table 1 and table 2 then table 3. This was a big help for me. Thanks again.